# Keep a daemon running on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

Please note this is a **FreeBSD** question and not a Linux question. Please don't answer with how it would be done on Linux or `systemd` or any of that.

I have a situation where `memcached` is crashing. It's not that repeatable and I'll eventually figure it out. In the meantime, I need to ensure that `memcached` is running. If it's not, I need to restart it. It is installed via `pkg` and starts via `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/memcached`. There are a few choices.

1. I could write a watchdog script and invoke it every like 10 minutes or something via `cron`. Kinda ugly, but would work. Main thing here is that I need to go write that script. Calling `service memcached status`, evaluate the result, maybe call `service memcached start`. I know how to write that, but it seems clunky. I'd rather just use a mechanism that already exists.
2. I could write a `do ... until` loop script. Then I could modify `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/memcached`. But I want to keep files that were installed by the package pristine. I don't want to perpetuate my changes each time I upgrade the package.
3. I drop a script into `/usr/local/etc/periodic.d/hourly` and have it invoked by `periodic(8)`.

Is there some easy, FreeBSD-native mechanism that I'm not thinking of to keep processes running? Or am I just overthinking it and I should just go write my 8 line script and start calling it from `cron`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *supervisor*. I don't think FreeBSD comes with one out of the box. But there are some in the ports. I see at least;

- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) is available as a port called [`py-supervisor`](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/py-supervisor/) (the port has several flavors, install with `pkg install py37-supervisor` or whatever matches your Python version).
- [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) is available as a [port](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/daemontools/).
- [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) is available as a [port](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/monit).
- [FSCD](https://github.com/bsdtrhodes/freebsd-fscd/) is available as a port called [`fsc`](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/fsc).

I suggest supervisord. Install the package and add a stanza to `/usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf`:

```
[program:memcached]
command=/usr/local/etc/rc.d/memcached
```

To run supervisord at boot time, edit `/etc/rc.conf` or `/etc/rc.conf.local` to have the line

```
supervisord_enable="YES"
```

Whichever supervisor you choose, make sure to disable the direct starting of `memcached`.

Comment: I'm confused. You've linked to a man page. So this obviously exists. I'm running 12.1-RELEASE-p8. But `man supervise` and `man 8 supervise` both come up empty on my system. Likewise `pkg search supervise` comes up empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PacoHope My bad, I'd read that man page too quickly and hadn't realized this wasn't a new basic FreeBSD program, but the old daemontools utility, which is part of a port. (I don't understand why the FreeBSD web interface shows a seemingly random set of ports.) I would generally not recommend daemontools because it's its own world (a bit like systemd…) so I've changed my recommendation to supervisord and also added a couple more alternatives (not an exhaustive list).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the restart with `daemon(1)` using the `-r` flag. Much simpler, IMHO. BTW, I maintain the memcached port, so I may be able to help with the memcached crashing issue, let me know details if you want.